# Adding 3D animation on site?

Tags: web-mapping, 3d, animation, blendergis

I'm trying to find how i could animate a map online with no result.

I've an application that users can use to query place. The result include a map. All data are store locally on a server. Now i want the map to display some informations like from train station, move to the nearest hotel with animated 3D route and at the hotel location shows hotels pictures in popup or similar. So moving from place A to B shows an animated 3D route. Ariving at place B shows some animated pictures of the place (in 3D or 2D).

Is there any possibility to use a 3D program like blender (Or Adobe After Effect) to create surch animations live?

That is the moment the user enter the query, the map is displayed in an animated state and live.